# Undefined Property . Cannot call the object attributes on other page

Tags: php, model-view-controller

I'm starting to develop a simple MVC application . I call the  function below in my controller

```
public function show()
    {
        if (!isset($_GET['id']))
            return call('pages', 'error');
        $ingredient = Ingredients::find($_GET['id']);
        require_once('views/ingredients/show.php');
    }
```

I am unable to access the `$ingredient`objects attributes like `$ingredient->item_id` or any attributes in the **show.php** . But able to call the objects attributes within the same function.

My **show.php** page looks like this

```html
<p>This is the requested Ingredients:</p>

<p><?php echo $ingredient->item_id; ?></p>
<p><?php echo $ingredient->stock_id; ?></p>
<p><?php echo $ingredient->item_qunatity; ?></p>
<p><?php echo $ingredient->item_unit; ?></p>
```

My model looks like this . Name of this class is Ingredients

`public static function find($id) {
        $database = Database::getInstance();
        $id = intval($id);
        $query = $database->prepare('SELECT * FROM ingredients WHERE id = :id');
        $query->execute(array('id' => $id));
        $ingredient = $query->fetch();
        return new     Ingredients($ingredient['id'],$ingredient['item_id'],$ingredient['stock_id'], $ingredient['item_quantity'],$ingredient['item_unit']);
    }`

Comment: are you calling show() function before you are printing $ingredient ?

Comment: yes . I'm calling the function before .It's happening if I store in a variable within the function and print the variable in show.php instead .

Comment: After getting data from $ingredient = Ingredients::find($_GET['id']); , dump $ingredient , is this giving all value? let me know

Comment: You use tags for both cakephp and codeigniter-3. Are you mixing these two frameworks somehow?

Comment: What exactly does `Ingredients::find()` return?

Comment: No I'm not mixing both . I'm not using any frameworks as of now . dump displays the values of the object .

Comment: Ingredients::find() returns an object.

Comment: @prithivraj : refer my answer, i got info why this is happening.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that you define those functions in the scope of one method, whilst trying to access them inside the scope of another method. Those are two separate things.

To accomplish something like that you have to either declare the variable in the global scope (considered bad practice), or store it inside the objects properties.